# solr excluding results filtered by geofilt

Tags: solr, lucene

q=*:*&fq={!geofilt%20pt=41.93825,-93.38989%20sfield=site_opplocation%20d=100}

This query filters all the indexes to those that lie inside this circle of radius 100km. What I want to do is exclude these and give the rest. Have not been able to figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
q=*:* AND -_query_:"{!geofilt d=100}"&pt=41.93825,-93.38989&sfield=site_opplocation
```

the trick is to use the *query* special hack, you can negate that one.